# MS Detours 2.1 - Unresolved externals

Tags: c++, winapi, detours

I'm using MS Detours 2.1 Library and VS 2010. I'm trying to detour PlaySoundW function.

I can't compile that code and I'm getting these errors:

`Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   (...)\detoursLearning.dll   detoursLearning`

`Error  1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PlaySoundW@12  (...)\detoursLearning\main.obj  detoursLearning`

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <detours.h>

namespace Hooks
{
    BOOL(__stdcall *OrgPlaySoundW)(LPCTSTR pszSound, HMODULE hmod, DWORD fdwSound) = &PlaySoundW;

    BOOL HookPlaySoundW(LPCTSTR pszSound, HMODULE hmod, DWORD fdwSound)
    {
        Beep(1000, 250);
        return TRUE;
    }

    void DetourPlaySoundW(BOOL disable)
    {
        if(!disable)
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW, HookPlaySoundW);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
        } else 
        {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW, HookPlaySoundW);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
        }
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Hooks::DetourPlaySoundW(FALSE);
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Hooks::DetourPlaySoundW(TRUE);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

One more thing, can you explain me this:

```
&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not linking to winmm.lib.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680%28VS.85%29.aspx

Martyn

Comment: That worked, thx. ONE MORE THING:

Can you explain me this:

&(PVOID&)OrgPlaySoundW